# Db2 sql dump tools

Tags: db2

I am searching for tools to dump db2 tables (like sqlyog or MySQL browser in MySQL).

Can you suggest me some?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "dump db2 tables"?  sqlyog looks like a web-based administration tool, not just a tool to "dump mysql tables"

Comment: I mean ...export table ddl and table content (INSERT INTO ) to sql script.

if we using sqlyog we can exeport database or table as sql dump and save result as sql script

Comment: looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925519/sql-dump-from-db2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DB2 ships with a utility called `db2look` that will do what you're looking for.  Try this command:

```
 db2look -d MYDATABASE -a -e -o mydatabase.sql
```

If you're looking to take the data with you, the command `db2move` could also be useful.  Effectively, it does a db2look as described above, and also exports the data from every table.  Then on your new database, you can import and be good to go.  In my experience, we used this to migrate from DB2 running on Windows to DB2 on Linux.

```
 db2move MYDATABASE EXPORT
```

Loading on the other instance is equally easy:

```
 db2move MYDATABASE IMPORT
```

Check `db2move -h` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Can you describe what you exactly want to do? Do you stay within the db2 realm or do you want to import that stuff in a different DBMS like SQL Server or Oracle?

One option would be to generate the DDL using the 'Generate DDL' Option that is available in the DB2 Control Center or the `db2look` tool (Control Center calls this tool). The data you can dump by running the `export` command. This will create an CSV file which you can import using the `import` command. You might be able to import the data using a different Database engine (MS SQL Server or Oracle).

Answer (score 0):

IBM data movement tool would help you to unload/load data as well as database schema:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0906datamovement/